# More precise square root of a value

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

To get a square root value of `mainlabelString`, I am using

```
- (IBAction)rootPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSString *mainLabelString = mainLabel.text;

    int mainLabelValue = [mainLabelString longLongValue];

    NSString *calculatedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", sqrt(mainLabelValue)];

    mainLabel.text = calculatedValue;

}
```

And although it does work with numbers such as 88, from which I get 9.380832, it does not for example work with that number, for which it says the square root is 3.000000 (instead of 3.062814).
I tried replacing `longLongValue` with `doubleValue` and `integerValue` but it doesn't change it.
What's wrong?

Comment: You should do more research before posting here. This is the third time in the last three hours you've posted this same block of code with different questions about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value into the text field is like @"9.0001", getting the long long value truncates the decimal part.You said that you also have tried doubleValue, but I suspect that you did something like this:

```
int mainLabelValue = [mainLabelString doubleValue];
```

Instead of:

```
double mainLabelValue = [mainLabelString doubleValue];
```

In the first case the number loses the decimal part too, because an int can't store the decimal part, nor a long long int.
Let me know how you exactly tried to retrieve the double value of the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` it provides very wide range and different styles(Decimaland scientific etc).[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)